# Assembly algorithm

Tags: assembly, sparc

This is my algorithm to keep dividing the number by 2 until the quotient reaches 0 it stops, but i need to print the remainders for it to be in binary and i attempted in my code below. But when i run it , it doesn't print anything.

```
 a = userInput/2
 if (a doesNotEqual 0)
 {
  while(quotient doesNotEqual 0)
  { 
    quotient=a/2
    a = quotient
   }
 }
```

!!!!!!

```
.section ".data"

prompt: .asciz "\nEnter a number: "
format: .asciz "%d"


prompt2: .asciz "\nPlease choose one of the following options: \n 1. Print the number in binary seperating each 4 bits with a space. \n"
prompt3: .asciz " 2. blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah. \n 3. blahblahbalhblahblahbla. \n"
prompt4: .asciz " 4. blahblahblahblahblahblahblahb \n 5. Enter in a new number \n 6. Quit the program\n\n"
format2: .asciz "%d"


string: .asciz "\nYou entered option: %d\n"

string1: .asciz "%d"




define(a,l0)
define(quotient, l1)
define(remainder, l2)


!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
.align 4
input: .word 0
input2: .word 0


.align 4
.section ".text"
.global main
main:
save %sp, -96, %sp


clr   %a
clr   %quotient

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
set   prompt, %o0
call  printf
nop
set   format, %o0
set   input, %o1
call  scanf
nop
ld   [%o1], %g1                  ! g1 = userInput #


set   prompt2, %o0               ! menu
call  printf
nop
set   prompt3, %o0
call  printf
nop
set   prompt4, %o0
call  printf
nop
                                 ! menu
set   format2, %o0
set   input2, %o1
call  scanf
nop
set  input2, %o1
ld   [%o1], %g2                 ! g2 = option selected
set  string, %o0
mov  %g2, %o1
call printf
nop                             ! this is a check to see that g2 is indeed the option selected

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!problem somewhere below
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

mov   %g1, %o0
call  .div
mov   2, %o1
mov   %o0, %a                      ! a = input #/2
cmp   %a, 0                        ! if (a doesNotEqual 0)
be    done

test:

cmp   %quotient, 0                ! while(quotient doesNotEqual 0)
be    done1
nop
mov   %a, %o0
call  .div
mov   2, %o1                      
mov   %o0, %quotient              ! quotient = a/2


mov   %a, %o0
call  .rem
mov   2, %o1
mov   %o0, %remainder
set   string1, %o0
mov   %remainder, %o1
call  printf
nop

mov   %quotient, %a               ! a = quotient

ba    test
nop

done:
done1:

ret
restore
```

Comment: This looks like SPARC to me? What platform are you on, have you tried using [gdb](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/) to debug your code? You may also want to study the arguments to the [functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Formatted-Input.html) you're calling here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you interleave the `nl` between `input` and `input2`, the latter will no longer be aligned, hence the bus error. By the way, I have seen you do this `nl` thing multiple times, and I believe I have told you it makes no sense at all. `scanf` doesn't use the third parameter because the format string only has one field specifier, and even if it did, it wouldn't be a newline.

You might have other problems too, this is just the first one I spotted. Learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Im trying to convert the userInput # to binary. From the code above, it asks for userInput#, then it prints a menu, user selects a option, it prints the option, and it should convert the decimal to binary right after no matter what option you choose (getting the algorithm correct first). So for example the userInput = 9. Keep dividing by 2 until the quotient = 0 and the remainders from last to first is the binary number. 9/2=4 with remainder 1. 4/2=2 with remainder 0. 2/2=1 with remainder 0. 1/2=0 with remainder 1 So the binary for 9 is the remainders from last to first so it is 1001.